# xsi:nil="true" con XmlDocument en vb

Tags: c#, xml, vb

Buenas Intento agregar un elemento a un `Doc XML`, pero indicando que este sera nulo,  pero no logro hacerlo como me lo exigen, si me pueden dar una ayuda se los agradecería, mi código:

```
     Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument()

     Dim xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", String.Empty)
     Dim root = doc.DocumentElement()
     doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root)

     Dim eleFactura = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "facturaComputarizadaEstandar", String.Empty)
     doc.AppendChild(eleFactura)

     Dim eleCabecera = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "cabecera", String.Empty)
     eleFactura.AppendChild(eleCabecera)

     Dim elemento = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "nitEmisor", String.Empty)
     Dim valor = doc.CreateTextNode("12345678")
     elemento.AppendChild(valor)
     eleCabecera.AppendChild(elemento)

     elemento = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "pruebannul", String.Empty)
     Dim valNull = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "nil")
     valNull.Value = "true"
     elemento.Attributes.Append(valNull)
     eleCabecera.AppendChild(elemento)

     Dim settings As New Xml.XmlWriterSettings()

     settings.Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False) ''sin bom
     settings.Indent = True

     ''Escribir en Disco--------------------------------------------
     Using writer As Xml.XmlWriter = Xml.XmlWriter.Create("d:\xmlDoc2.xml", settings)
        doc.Save(writer)
        writer.Close()
     End Using

     '' Escribir en Memoria, para no estar leyendo lo escrito en Disco -----
     Dim strBui As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
     Using writer As Xml.XmlWriter = Xml.XmlWriter.Create(strBui, settings)
        doc.Save(writer)
        writer.Close()
     End Using

     Dim strres = strBui.ToString.Replace("utf-16", "utf-8")
     Console.WriteLine(strres)
```

El resultado obtenido con este código es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<facturaComputarizadaEstandar>
  <cabecera>
    <nitEmisor>12345678</nitEmisor>
    <montoDescuento p3:xsi="true" xmlns:p3="nil" />
  </cabecera>
</facturaComputarizadaEstandar>
```

Pero necesito obtener:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<facturaComputarizadaEstandar>
  <cabecera>
    <nitEmisor>12345678</nitEmisor>
    <montoDescuento xsi:nil="true" />
  </cabecera>
</facturaComputarizadaEstandar>
```

Y también quería saber si existe alguna manera de poder escribir en disco y al mismo tiempo obtenerlo en una cadena lo que se esta escribiendo, para que así no tenga que hacer 2 veces el proceso de `Xml.XmlWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Respondo yo mismo:

```
  Dim elemento = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "MontoDes", String.Empty)
  Dim attribute As Xml.XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("nil", strXSI)
  attribute.Value = "true"
  elemento.Attributes.Append(attribute)
  eleCabecera.AppendChild(elemento)
```

Codigo Completo por si a alguien le sirve:

```
 Dim strXSI As String = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  Dim strXSD As String = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

  Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument()
  Dim schema As New Xml.Schema.XmlSchema()
  schema.Namespaces.Add("xsi", strXSI)
  schema.Namespaces.Add("xsd", strXSD)
  doc.Schemas.Add(schema)

  Dim xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", String.Empty)
  Dim root = doc.DocumentElement()
  doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root)

  Dim eleFactura = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "facturaComputarizadaEstandar", String.Empty)
  eleFactura.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", strXSI)
  eleFactura.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", strXSD, "facturaComputarizadaEstandar.xsd")
  doc.AppendChild(eleFactura)

  Dim eleCabecera = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "cabecera", String.Empty)
  eleFactura.AppendChild(eleCabecera)

  Dim elemento = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "nitEmisor", String.Empty)
  Dim valor = doc.CreateTextNode("12345678")
  elemento.AppendChild(valor)
  eleCabecera.AppendChild(elemento)

  elemento = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "MontoDes", String.Empty)
  Dim attribute As Xml.XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("nil", strXSI)
  attribute.Value = "true"
  elemento.Attributes.Append(attribute)
  eleCabecera.AppendChild(elemento)

  Dim settings As New Xml.XmlWriterSettings()

  settings.Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False) '' carlos sin bom
  settings.Indent = True

  ''Carlos: Escribir en Disco------------------------------------------------------------
  Using writer As Xml.XmlWriter = Xml.XmlWriter.Create("d:\xmlDoc2.xml", settings)
     doc.Save(writer)
     writer.Close()
  End Using

  ''Carlos: Escribir en Memoria, para no estar leyendo lo escrito en Disco ----------------
  Dim strBui As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
  Using writer As Xml.XmlWriter = Xml.XmlWriter.Create(strBui, settings)
     doc.Save(writer)
     writer.Close()
  End Using

  Dim strres = strBui.ToString.Replace("utf-16", "utf-8")
  Console.WriteLine(strres)
```

Nota: NO hallo aun como hacer que escriba en disco y obtenerlo al mismo tiempo en memoria